# Can we use OpenCV in android JUnit test?

Tags: android, opencv, junit

I am now writing a test case under **"app/src/androidTest"**, which need to involve OpenCV lib.
I've tried :
1. Import OpenCV 3.2.0 as a module.
2. Import OpenCV lib as suggested , [Here is the link](https://github.com/rajamalw/opencv-android-gradle).
But anyway the import seems to fail,
```

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.w(TAG, "static initializer: Load opencv failed !!!");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "static initializer: Load opencv succeed .");
    }
}
```

```
Any comment would by helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

To load OpenCV for android test (on Windows)

Download the OpenCV version for Windows and unzip it.

Copy the following file inside your android project (I putted it inside /app/src/main/jniLibs/win/)  :

"yourunzipath" + opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java331.dll

Then, inside your Android test folder, create the following class :

```
public class OpenCVTestInitializer {

    @Before
    public void initOpenCV() {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String opencvpath = projectPath + "/app/src/main/jniLibs/win/";
        System.load(opencvpath + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");
    }

}
```

To finish, each test class you want to use with OpenCV must extend the previous class.